# Bootstrap-Saas: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I am getting the following error. According to my R&D i believe it is producing because of `bootstrap-sass` but how can i resolve it I have tried very hard but still unable to get something.

ruby -v = 1.9.3
rails   = 3.2.2

**GemFile**

```
"bootstrap-sass", "~> 2.0.0" # this is out of assets group

ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load paths:
  /var/www/eventdid
  /var/www/eventdid/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/app/assets/stylesheets
  /var/www/eventdid/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.6/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  (in /var/www/eventdid/app/assets/stylesheets/site.css.scss)):
```

I have been digging my head into this issue from hours and hours. Looking forward help from you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using pre-compiled assets you should move your

```
gem 'sass-rails'
```

also out of your assets group.

Also worth checking, you should use scss in your application.css.scss

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap";
@import "twitter/bootstrap-responsive";
```